# I am new in codeigniter and i am trying to join 3 table but it gives some issu

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

[image]I have 3 table like `ts_users` ,  `ts_acc_category` `ts_user`
I am trying to join like this

```
$this->db->select('*');

$this->db->from('ts_voucher');
$this->db->join('ts_users','ts_users.user_id = ts_voucher.id');
$this->db->join('ts_acc_category','ts_voucher.user_id = ts_acc_category.acc_cat_id');

$this->db->where('user_reg_type','bill_party');
```

And error is

```
<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
        <p>Error Number: 1054</p><p>Unknown column 'ts_voucher.user_id' in 'on clause'</p><p>SELECT *
FROM `ts_voucher`
JOIN `ts_users` ON `ts_users`.`user_id` = `ts_voucher`.`id`
JOIN `ts_acc_category` ON `ts_voucher`.`user_id` = `ts_acc_category`.`acc_cat_id`
WHERE `user_reg_type` = 'bill_party'</p><p>Filename: models/reports/ExpensesModel.php</p><p>Line Number: 32</p> </div>
```

Please tell me where i am wrong in my code

Comment: field `user_reg_type` which table to belong

Comment: in ts_users table

Comment: In the join between users and vouchers, you try to use `\`ts_voucher\`.\`id\``; in the next join, I see `\`ts_voucher\`.\`user_id\``.

Comment: two field are there in table of `ts_voucher` so also i add two diffrent id used in join ):

Comment: i also tell that @KhanMuntazar share your table structure so we can esay to solved their problem

Comment: @KhanMuntazar It's not a perfect database structure to join. where is a foreign key? please change your database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=>Try this..

```
$this->db->select('tv.*,tu.*,tac.*'); //select field what you might want to select. 
        $this->db->from('ts_voucher as tv');
        $this->db->join('ts_users tu','tu.user_id = tv.id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('ts_acc_category as tac','tv.user_id = tac.acc_cat_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('tv.user_reg_type','bill_party');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('tv.*,tu.*,tac.*'); //select field what you might want to select. 
        $this->db->from('ts_voucher as tv');
        $this->db->join('ts_users tu','tu.user_id = tv.id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('ts_acc_category as tac','tv.user_id = tac.acc_cat_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('tv.user_reg_type','bill_party');
```

Comment: know it gives me this error <p>Error Number: 1054</p><p>Unknown column 'ts_voucher.user_id' in 'on clause'</p>

Comment: give me name of id ts_voucher table check proper database field name

Comment: ts_voucher  id name is "id"

Comment: check edited answer & in db record are there or not in ts_users

Comment: if not working then share your structure db screen shot so i show proper each table field

Comment: <p>Error Number: 1054</p><p>Unknown column 'tv.user_id' in 'on clause'</p>

Comment: or also its a record problem? so you can re-enter once data in your project and then check

Comment: @MohammadMalek you are not set "select field what you might want to select." like. 
$this->db->select('tv.*,tu.*,tac.*'); it's not a simple select query.

Comment: yeppp bro (: (:

Comment: @MohammadMalek image of table structure is uploaded

Comment: @MohammadMalek its give me empty array

Comment: bro plz check your table our query is proper when common id match the data is always fetch

Comment: its my pleasure @KhanMuntazar

Answer (score 0):

you don't user_id field in your ts_voucher table please check that first

Comment: sorry i'm not understand what you say

Comment: the error says you dont have the user_id field in your ts_voucher table .if possible can you share the table structure in the question

Comment: table structure is upload please check

Comment: you have to create a new field in ts_voucher i.e user_id and save the user_id there also.After that only you can get the records